# Posting Updates to Facebook Fan Pages using Graph API?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, facebook

I want to post on face book page using Graph API.The code will be in Asp.Net with c#.Just need to know how can i post to face book page(not account).I am able to send into account,now want to post in page.I refereed this link [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api)

please help me to solve the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a working code in PHP, hopefully, you can make it work for c#.

Basically, I'm using php-curl for the url feed of the fan page.
You should be able to find a c# wrapper/binding for curl, maybe this [libcurl for .NET](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/dotnet/)

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed";

$attachment =  array(

          'access_token' => 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN',
          'message' => 'your message',
                'name' => "your title",
                'link' => "your link",
                'description' => "your description",

        );

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);

$result= curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: @Soufiane Hassou:Thanks,have you tested it?I have tried that but it is posting on respective account not the page.

Comment: Yes, it is tested actually. Remember, you need to give a PAGE_ID not a user_id, maybe that's the problem ?

Comment: Soufiane Hassou:yes I had given page id.

Comment: Is access token different for page?

Comment: Do you know the procedure,how to create token for page?means when i run or execute my coe it will go for facebook site here i have to put my details.but don't know how to generate token for page?Please help to solve it.

Comment: Try opening this link https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id=<APP_ID>&client_secret=<APP_SECRET> with your application secret and it.

Comment: @Soufiane Hassou :I already made this,but this accesstoken is not working for page.It posted to the respective account.